# How to store users location on CloudKit in swift?

Tags: swift, location, cloudkit

I'm trying to store a users journey and upload it to CloudKit.

The following takes the users location whenever they move more than 5 meters and uploads as a string but I want it to be uploaded as a location list or similar so it can be pulled down later.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let location = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    addCrumbPoint(center)

    let message = "{\"lat\":\(location!.coordinate.latitude),\"lng\":\(location!.coordinate.longitude), \"alt\": \(location!.altitude)}"

    let newSweet = CKRecord(recordType: "Sweet")
    newSweet["content"] = message

    let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    publicData.saveRecord(newSweet, completionHandler: { (record:CKRecord?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("woo")
        }else{
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

The documentation on using Location and CloudKit is written in Objective-C so any help would be brilliant.

[CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_Framework_Reference/)

[CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a CKRecordID and a CKRecord. Then you set the last retrieved CLLocation on the CKRecord.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
  let location = locations.last!
  let id = CKRecordID(recordName: "01")
  let locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "location", recordID: id)
  locationRecord.setObject(location, forKey: "location")
  // or locationRecord["location"] = location
  let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
  publicData.saveRecord(locationRecord) { record, error in
    //
  }
}
```